How to use Lambda@Edge in CloudFront to block an IP address
We use a CF distribution and ALB that connects to EC2 instances to provide API endpoints to the internet.
On those EC2s we have an API system with many endpoints. They all start with api.company.com
Example:
api.company.com/api_1
api.company.com/api_2
api.company.com/extra_secure_api

Most endpoints are public. But
api.company.com/extra_secure_api 

should be only allowed to request from few source IPs.
I first looked at adding an extra rule to an existing WebACL from the WAF we have attached to our ALB.
I found two problems there. If I only allow the IP Set, I deny access for all IPs not in the list for every request to the ALB. But I stopped trying to to continue with WAF, because when I tried to save the rule I get a message I am not allowed to add extra rules. (I work in big company and having the provided WebAcl attached to all resources is mandatory, because the WebAcl is a general WebAcl for the company I am not able to add/change it)
Then I looked at Lambda@Edge attached to a behavior from the specific distributions for the APIs.
The first test basically worked fine. I used an IP not in the whitelisted and got the message No Access. But I don't know what if the IP is in the whitelist. In that case I like CloudFront to just continue the request, send it to the ALB.
The basic code I have now is stated below. I hoped that only not do a specific return from lambda would return in CloudFront continuing the request. But that was a bit naive maybe. I could write an else statement possibly that in case IP address matches I do a request the the ALB, but then we have the issue of ALB only accepting traffic from CloudFront.
I hope you can help me here with some information. I tried to look on internet but could not find documentation about my specific case. Any help would be very much appreciated.
The Lambda@Edge example:
import json

white_listed_ips = ['1.2.3.4', '3.4.5.6']


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    request = event['Records'][0]['cf']['request']

    if request['clientIp'] not in white_listed_ips:
        return {
            'status': 200,
            'body': 'No Access'
        }
    else:
        return request


Solution found. I added grabbing the request, and return the request in case ip address is know in the whitelisted ips.
